ssh remote port forwarding in systemd
I would like to execute this command
ssh -R 2200:localhost:80 user@"myddns.net"

at every startup of my fedora system (note that the command itself is working in a shell).
I thought to use systemd instead of crond.
I created the file /etc/systemd/user/myssh.service :
[Unit]
Description=Ssh remote for myssh
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
#User=
#Group=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh -R 2200:localhost:80 user@"myddns.net"
Restart=on-failure
StandardOutput=file:%h/log_file

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

I enabled and started it but the command did not work :
systemctl --user enable myssh.service
systemctl --user start myssh.service

here is some log :
➜  ~ journalctl --user -u myssh     
août 28 12:33:06 lausanne systemd[1419]: Started myssh.service - ssh remote for Lausanne.

It may be because ssh -R is an interactive command and not suitable for systemd (or crond). Could still be it done in this way ?

I would add -N option.
As per man ssh

-N      Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just forwarding ports.  Refer to the description of SessionType in ssh_config(5) for details.

